# Angular file upload is not sending object to server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want user to select file and display to client side , so for that i am sending file to server so i can read the content and send back to client but when i send object it always get empty object to server with below code, Any idea what is implemented wrong or any better approach to upload file to server ?

```
//Controller.js

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                console.log('file is ');
                console.dir(file);
                var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };

// Service.js in service i see data `file` data is printed 

angular.module('App').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
      this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    console.log('service called', fd);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(resp){
    console.log('success');
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
}]);
```

Server

```
//routes.js 

export default function(app) {
  // Insert routes below
  app.post('/fileUpload', require('./api/fileUpload'));
}

//index.js 

    var express = require('express');
    var controller = require('./fileUpload.controller');

    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/fileUpload',controller.create);


    module.exports = router;

//controller.js

    export function create(req, res) {
    console.log('fileUpload controller server',req.body);
    }
```

Comment: Try posting the file object in FormData. `var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);` . I never used transformRequest while file upload, so not sure about it.

Comment: ok i did that and i see on client side is printing `console.log('service called', fd);` `{}` object. Any clue when we have `new FormData` why its creating empty object ? question updated

Comment: I don't think you could print formData like that. Go to browser developer tools and check the request in the network tab.

Comment: in my server side nodejs  controller `console.log('fileUpload controller server',req.body);` is not gettign anything

Comment: also network tab is showing url status pending